# OpenSSL: waking a thread while blocking from BIO_do_accept

Tags: c, openssl, pthreads, blocking

I have a server that accepts multiple clients using a blocking implementation of BIO_do_accept, and each time a client connects, BIO_do_accept returns, I create a new thread to handle the connection, and call BIO_do_accept again in the main thread to accept more connections.

However, I need to be able to stop the thread that is blocked by BIO_do_accept.  The only solution I have thought of for this is to use the nonblocking implementation, and when the function returns, check a global variable to determine whether or not the thread needs to quit, and if so free memory and use pthread_exit, and if not, run another thread with pthread_yield.

I don't think I can use signals because I need to free the BIO object, and it may be bad to free memory and pthread_exit all from within the signal handler.

Does anyone know a better solution to this, or is a combination of global variables/polling/pthread_exit really the best solution?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing this with OpenSSL BIOs, but the typical way of doing something like this is by making the socket non-blocking (with `fcntl(2)`), beginning an async `accept(2)` call, and then using `select(2)` on the socket and a pipe to wait until either the `accept` finishes or data is written into the pipe.

Comment: Sending a signal to the blocking thread would make it return from the internal call to `accept()`. Just make sure the signal handler had been installed using the flag `SA_RESTART`. On signal reception `accept()` would fail and `errno` would have been set to `EINTR`. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html and http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html

Comment: Set some 'abort' flag that a BIO_do_accept() always checks on return before it does anything else, then make the call return by opening a temporary client connection on the local TCP stack.